# How to animate a container that moves from top to bottom and again it should not appear from top to bottom but continue from bottom to top

Tags: css, reactjs

For context check this https://www.intercom.com/ url and navigate to People are talking container where the container moves to left to right. I need the same animation for my code but I unable to do that. Here's the url for https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-elion-94spb?file=/src/styles.css for my codesandbox code.[image]

Comment: Your description of what is needed does not match the people are talking system which has the elements moving continuously. Do you want continuous movement upwards of your element(s)? Or do you want it to alternate between going upwards to going downwards?

Comment: I want the elements to continuously move towards up to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `move` animation to this:

```
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  50% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Your previous code is going from down to up, then instantly resetting to down. This code goes from down to up, then back down again, and repeats.